# What does methodOn?

Tags: spring-boot, rest

I am new to Spring. I am studying Rest Webservices.
In the book *Spring in Action* I found the following code:

```
import static org.springframework.hateoas.server.mvc.WebMvcLinkBuilder.linkTo;
import static org.springframework.hateoas.server.mvc.WebMvcLinkBuilder.methodOn;
.....................
@GetMapping("/recent")
  public CollectionModel<EntityModel<Taco>> recentTacos() {
    PageRequest page = PageRequest.of(
            0, 12, Sort.by("createdAt").descending());

    List<Taco> tacos = tacoRepo.findAll(page).getContent();

    //tag::recentsHateoas3[]
    CollectionModel<EntityModel<Taco>> recentResources = CollectionModel.wrap(tacos);
    recentResources.add(
        linkTo(methodOn(DesignTacoController.class).recentTacos())
             .withRel("recents"));
    //end::recentsHateoas3[]
    return recentResources;
  }
```

- I saw in the documentation that methodOn return an object of type DesignTacoController so I don't understand what it brings when we fire the rencentTacos method!
  What is the difference with directly calling the method recentTacos form the Controller?

Answer (score 1):

`methodOn(...)` returns a dummy proxy of the controller, the actual method is not called. It is only so that you can obtain a link corresponding to a mapped controller method in a type-safe way.

Firing `recentTacos` on that object tells Spring you want the URL to which `recentTacos` is mapped. This is better than using an URL string, because changes to the URL do not force you to update your `linkTo` calls.